# menu items on the navigation bar and company icon on the left side of the nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following code on my web page:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:100%; ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
        
            <img  src="~/Images/InfoOrange.png" alt="ACR" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
 
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">Test City</span><br />Test Company</span>

    </span>
     
       <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <%-- <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>--%>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Users
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Details</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Depatment.aspx">Department</a>
     
         <%-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sections</a>--%>
        </div>
      </li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="admindropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Admin
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="NewBoxFolder.aspx">Box/Folder</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuration</a>

        </div>
      </li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
               <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="recordsDropDown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Records
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="FileUpload.aspx">BlockChain Upload</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Verify</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="DocReport.aspx">Report</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="BucketList.aspx">S3 List</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
          
  </div>
</nav>
```

when I see the navbar and the menu items on the web page. They look like this:

[image]

I want to bring the logo and the company name to the left side of the navbar and menu items on the right side of the menu bar and I want the menu items to be seen horizontally rather than vertically. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you click **full-page** when viewing the snippet. Everything should be positioned how you want but didn't want to mess around with your drop-down menu items because I assume you have `js` or something for those. You can put `media-queries` on to adjust the responsiveness of the browser.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:100%; ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
        
            <img  src="~/Images/InfoOrange.png" alt="ACR" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
 
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">Test City</span><br />Test Company</span>

    </span>
     
       <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <!-- <li class="nav-item active--><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Users
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Details</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Depatment.aspx">Department</a>
     
         <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sections</a>-->
        </div>
      </li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="admindropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Admin
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="NewBoxFolder.aspx">Box/Folder</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuration</a>

        </div>
      </li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
               <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="recordsDropDown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Records
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="FileUpload.aspx">BlockChain Upload</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Verify</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="DocReport.aspx">Report</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="BucketList.aspx">S3 List</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
          
  </div>
</nav>
```